# How to get text from textbox onclick checkbox in listview using android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am working on checkbox example. I have checkbox and textview (The textview value is I am getting from database) in ListView by using that when I click on checkbox then I am getting text of textview but it's returning only text id not value. Also, I want to get text in textview or unique id of particular row where I click in the front of checkbox and it's getting same id for all textview. Please help me get unique id or text from textview.

Code for click checkbox event

```
  public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_me:
            if (checked) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'checkbox me..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inactivelistview);

                Username =username.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("prinnt username_=== "+username);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertbox.setMessage("Do you want activate?");

                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });

                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
               alertbox.show();
            } else
                break;
    }
}
```

listadapter xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inactivelistview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#429ed7"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_me"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

When I click on check box it checks, if check then in username String it returns the id of textview for all checkbox click event, but I want the text value in checkbox.
I tried lots of method but not working please help me if you have any idea,.

Comment: It,s getting 1st no of textview text only on click any row  checkbox

Comment: Can you add code where onCheckBoxClicked() is called?

Comment: I decared in xml  code  - android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"

Comment: This is just bad. You never going to know which item from list is clicked. And you  never going to get correct TextView with this implementation. You should check how you should handle list item click events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in this point

```
System.out.println("prinnt username_=== "+username);
```

you have to put "Username" instead of "username":

```
System.out.println("prinnt username_=== "+Username);
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working .But it,s getting only first no of position textview text  on click any row checkbox. please help.                                                Thanks in advanced............

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but the string that you get contains the text inside TextView. What position do you want?

Comment: In my listview ten textview username , but when i click on fifth line number of checkbox  username in textview it,s shows the username of  first line of username.

Comment: I am getting textviews value of first item(Position) in listview every time.

Comment: now i understand what do you mean about position, there are two ways to know the position, one is with an Adapter and other is with a Listener of your list. In Adapter there is a method getView that you must overidde that have position in parameters. In Listener there is the method onClick also with position parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  please can you brief explain in detail or u can edit my code where i have to change because i am fresher ..i cinfused..Thank you so much

Comment: Every listview has an Adapter and a Listener. Search on google and try, i think is better! ;)